# Upload de imagem com react native

Tags: react-native

Tenho esse código com react native que devia enviar uma imagem para meu back, porém me dar um erro . O código é esse a seguir

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, View, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image, Text, TextInput } from "react-native";
import background from "../../assets/por_do_sol.jpeg";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import api from "../services/api";


export default function RegisterImage() {
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState("");
  const [types, setTypes] = useState(false);
  const [upload, setUpload] = useState(null);
  function handleSelectTypeImage() {
    setTypes(true);
  }

  async function UploadImage() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", upload);
    console.log(formData)
    const { data } = await api.post("/posts", formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })

    // console.log(data)
  }

  async function handleSelectCamera() {
    setTypes(false);
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
    })
    if (result.error) {
      console.log("Error")
    } else {
      let prefix;
      let ext;
      if (result.fileName) {
        [prefix, ext] = result.fileName;
        ext = ext.toLowerCase() === 'heic' ? 'jpg' : ext;
      } else {
        prefix = new Date().getTime();
        ext = 'jpg'
      }
      const imageUpload = {
        uri: result.uri,
        type: result.type,
        name: `${prefix}.${ext}`
      }
      setUpload(imageUpload);
      setPreview(result.uri);
    }
  }
  async function handleSelectGalery() {
    setTypes(false);
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
    });
    if (result.error) {
      console.log("Error")
    } else {
      let prefix;
      let ext;
      if (result.fileName) {
        [prefix, ext] = result.fileName;
        ext = ext.toLowerCase() === 'heic' ? 'jpg' : ext;
      } else {
        prefix = new Date().getTime();
        ext = 'jpg'
      }
      const imageUpload = {
        uri: result.uri,
        type: result.type,
        name: `${prefix}.${ext}`
      }
      setUpload(imageUpload);
      setPreview(result.uri);
    }
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ImageBackground source={background} style={styles.back} >

        <View style={{
          marginTop: 100,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          width: 230,
          height: 240,
          borderWidth: preview ? 0 : 1,
          borderStyle: "dashed",
          borderColor: "#fff",
          borderRadius: 7,
        }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={() => handleSelectTypeImage()}
          >
            {types && (
              <View style={styles.containerType}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSelectGalery} >
                  <Text style={styles.textButton}>Selecionar da galeria</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSelectCamera}>
                  <Text style={styles.textButton}>Capturar da câmera</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            )}
            {preview.length > 0 ? (
              <Image style={styles.image} source={{
                uri: preview
              }} />
            ) :
              (<Text></Text>)}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.bioLabel}>Selecione uma imagem de perfil</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.bioButton}>
          <Text style={styles.Label} onPress={UploadImage}>Avançar</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </ImageBackground>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  back: {
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    resizeMode: "cover",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  image: {
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    resizeMode: "cover",
    borderRadius: 7
  },
  containerType: {
    width: 230,
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 5,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    zIndex: 1
  },
  textButton: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#777",
    marginBottom: 8
  },
  button: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  camera: {
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    resizeMode: "cover"
  },

  bioLabel: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: "center",
    marginTop: 10
  },
  Label: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: "center",
  },

  bioButton: {
    height: 50,
    width: 300,
    borderWidth: 0.3,
    borderColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 10,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff80"
  }
});
```

E o mesmo me retorna esse erro

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data]

Stack trace:
  src/pages/RegisterImage.js:26:4 in UploadImage$
  node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
  node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:30 in invoke
  node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
  node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
  node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:170:17 in <unknown>
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:45:7 in tryCallTwo
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:200:23 in doResolve
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:66:12 in Promise
  node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:169:27 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
  node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:192:38 in enqueue
  node_modules/@babel/runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:216:8 in async
  src/pages/RegisterImage.js:16:2 in UploadImage
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text/Text.js:237:27 in touchableHandlePress
  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Touchable/Touchable.js:878:34 in _performSideEffectsForTransition
```

Alguem pode me dar uma força? pois ja não sei o que fazer

Comment: `const { data } = await api.post(...)` - `Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: data`. Essa promise está sendo resolvida? Debugou pra ver se existe essa propriedade `data`?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu vi do seu exemplo, os dados da imagem vem de uma variável do state, e você pode capturar a imagem de duas formas, da galeria de imagens ou da câmera.

O "data" somente vai existir se a comunicação com a sua API não der problema. Você precisa colocar um "try/catch" para identificar melhor o erro. Pode ser problema no endereço de acesso a API ou na rota.

Aqui tem um exemplo de como mandar uma imagem para a API, a função recebe creio que vai te ajudar:

```js
import api from "../services/api";
async function enviar_imagem(imagem_recebida){
 try {
  const userAuthToken = "TOKEN_DE_ACESSO_A_API";
  const requestConfigFile = {
    headers: {
   Authorization: `bearer ${userAuthToken}`,
   "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  };
  const dataFile = new FormData();
  const fileURL = imagem_recebida.uri;
  const fileName = fileURL.split("/").pop();
  const ext = fileURL.split(".").pop();
  dataFile.append("file", {
    uri: fileURL, // Caminho da imagem
    name: fileName,
    type: "image/" + ext
  });
  const response = await api.post("/salvar_imagem", dataFile, requestConfigFile);
  console.log(response);
  const id_imagem = response.data.file.id;
  console.log(id_imagem);
 } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
 } 
}
```

Comment: Agradeço,o erro não vem da api,constatei que se eu tirar o formData,ela envia a requisição e me retorna uma resposta,porém se adiciono novamente o formData,ela consiste nesse erro